# Why don't I find folders and shortcuts inside the Windows Start Menu folder with Everything search?

Tags: everything

I use [Everything](https://www.voidtools.com/) search from voidtools which is an awesome free tool.

However, there are certain folders and files which I don't find. And I don't know why that is.

###### Case 1: I don't find the `Start Menu` folder

The `Start Menu` folder does exist but Everything doesn't find it:
[image]

I tried the following search strings:

```
Start Menu
"Start Menu"
Start Menu\
"Start Menu\"
folder:Start Menu
```

According to the [documentation](https://www.voidtools.com/support/everything/searching/), one can search for folders with the backslash as in `documents\`. And it finds the `documents` folder.

###### Case 2: I don't find shortcut files

There is a file named Zoom.lnk:
[image]

No search results here either:

[image]

###### Workaround

While writing this post, I noticed that I find everything when I just copy the `Programs` folder from inside the `Start Menu` and paste it somewhere else like, say, `c:\temp\Programs`. Then all the folder and shortcuts *.lnk files are found by Everything.

###### Version

- Everything Version 1.4.1.1022 (x64)
- Windows 10

Comment: Have you maybe [excluded that folder](https://www.voidtools.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=9373) from Everything?

Comment: @SaaruLindestøkke Holy cow, yes, that was it! Thank you so much! Note: I had to **un**tick _both_ `Exclude hidden files and folder` _and_ `Exclude system files and folders`. Unticking one of them was not enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seemed (and you've confirmed this in the comments) that you are excluding the folder you're trying to search.

To see what folders are excluded, go to [Settings -> Indexes -> Exclude](https://www.voidtools.com/support/everything/options/#exclude) and see if there are any "exclude" checkboxes checked and/or a filter is being applied in the "Include only files" or the "Exclude files" textbox:

[image: Screenshot of Everything Options screen, showing the exclude options]